# how to feed multipe files to command line in java without using shell

Tags: java, shell, input, command-line, inputstream

I am quite new to java, so it might be a stupid question. But I need it to be solved for my data structure class project...

So I am trying to feed my program with **2 different input files**. I know we can use Scanner and InputStreamReader to achieve this with 1 file, I don't know how I should do it with 2 files.

In some answers to similar questions with mine, someone mentioned shell which I think can probably solve this problem. However, I don't know anything about shell, so I am wondering if this problem can be solved **without writing a shell file**, and what the syntax would be for inputting multiple files in command line.

What I execute in command line(with 1 input file):

```
java UserInterfaceOrNot < input.txt > output.txt
```

I will post more code if needed.

**Code:**

```
public class UserInterfaceOrNot
{
    public static EventManager em;
    public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        UserInterfaceOrNot ui = new UserInterfaceOrNot();
        while (scn.hasNext()){ui.runData();}
        scn = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (scn.hasNext() && !scn.next().equals("x")){ui.runCommand();}
    }
```

Comment: You can give any number of arguments when you run the program. Eg: java UserInterfaceOrNot input1.txt input2.txt output.txt. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkSet I think so. But i don't know the difference between passing the files as arguments and putting them after "<"... Are they the same? Bcs my prof wrote a little bit of using "<" so I just assumed he wants us to do it that way.

Comment: Can you show me your code of how you interpret these arguments?

Comment: @MarkSet This is what I have had in my program. I have not tested it though, bcs I am not sure about whether this is the correct way at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java UserInterfaceOrNot input1.txt input2.txt output.txt
```

When you call your program as this, you're actually passing 3 arguments to your java `public static void main (String [] args)` method.
You can find these argument in order in that String array (`String [] args`).
To read the arguments:

1. String myFirstFile = args[0]; // this will be "input1.txt"
2. String mySecondFile = args[1]; // this will be "input2.txt"
3. String myOutputFile = args[2]; // this will be "output.txt"

You can read each file (input1 and input2) like this by creating another method

```
public String readFileAsString(String inputFile) throw IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Then in your main method you can call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UserInterfaceOrNot ui = new UserInterfaceOrNot();
    String inputFile1 = args[0];
    String inputFile2 = args[1];

    String input1AsString = ui.readFileAsString(inputFile1);
    String input2AsString = ui.readFileAsString(inputFile2);
    //continue with your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So we don't need to use "<" or ">" in command line for arguments? What are they for?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need "<" , ">". I think your proffesor was using it just as an example

Comment: Get u! Thanks a lot, that was really helpful!